# Finding the version of Java that generated a keystore file?

Tags: java, keystore, keytool

I am listing the contents of a keystore file using keytool. However, I do not know which version of Java was used to generate this keystore file.

Is there a way to grab this detail from a given keystore file?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: That detail is not present in the keystore file, and it is not required. The format hasn't changed in 18 years.

Comment: @EJP so does that mean that I can use the keystore file that was generated with Java 7 keytool on an application server that runs on Java 6? Will there be any compatibility issues that I need to consider?

Comment: Should work. My keystore was generated in about 2001 by Java 1.3, but that's forward compatibilty. I'm not aware of any format changes.

Comment: I plugged in the keystore from Java 7 to the application server on Java 6, and so far things look to be working normally. I will try to find a reference manual citation about this when I get a chance. Thank you for sharing your input!

Comment: I need to change my JCEKS keystore's password but don't know the keytool version that was used to create the keystore file. Is there going to be a problem if I go ahead and use a Java 11 keytool to update the password ?

To be precise, we did just that and our application started seeing a lot more CPU usage for retrieving the key from the keystore, I'm wondering how the password change could have caused this